# using extract in php to print array value

Tags: php

I'm using extract passing it an associative array `$arr` but it doesn't work properly. I pass the array to my function `extract($arr)` but when I want to extract value it doesn't work. how can use it correctly?

here my array:

```
$arr = array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'abc','address' => 'street abc');
```

Comment: What code do you use to `extract()` ?

Comment: Please provide a full example and use more verbose language than "it doesn't work properly". Voting to close.

Comment: What do you mean with what code?

Comment: I think he's trying to use this function http://php.net/manual/es/function.extract.php

Comment: @Juanma yes right this function...

Comment: @Juanma Clearly.. but without the full implementation and clearly defined outcome its impossible to answer.

Comment: well I simply pass my array to extract in this way: extract($arr) and after call variable extracted with their name like $id,$name or $address

Comment: @eng_mazzy What's the problem?! http://codepad.org/DFjzTHSZ Seems to work for me. I don't know why you seemingly refuse to add the relevant, reproducible parts of your code to your question like xthexder and I have done.

Comment: I prefer a foreach instead extract() http://codepad.org/4JUiwBac

Comment: I insert my code in the previously post...anyway I resolved anything...I made a mistake calling key...thanks

Comment: I mean previously comment no post...

Comment: @eng_mazzy Then where is the errant call to `key()`? You cherry-picked parts of your code to show us and left out the error. You see why I was so adamant about getting the reproducible circumstances? There's no way any of us could have helped you.. not even the answer you accepted :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using it like [this](http://codepad.org/cwcb0RzU) it should work.

```
<?php
$arr = array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'abc','address' => 'street abc');
extract($arr);
echo $id . "\n";
echo $name . "\n";
echo $address;
?>

Output:
1
abc
street abc
```

This code shows the output fine. Post your exact code so that we can reproduce the problem.